# Easy code help about matrix. How to change the elements in a given matrix?

Tags: code-generation

For example I have a matrix

```
A[1,1]={1,2,3,4};
```

Now I want to change the second element of `A[1,1]` to `5`,so my code is

```
A[1,1][[2]]=5;
```

but there will be some error messages.
what I want to get is

```
A[1,1]={1,5,3,4};
```

What needs to be noted in particular is that the matrix `A[1,1]` must have double corner mark. Because there are lots of matrix in my actual code, and I should difference them.

---

I came up a way to settle this. But It's a bit of tedious.

```
For[n = 1, n <= nt, n = n + 1, For[i = 1, i <= it, i = i + 1, A[n, i] = Array[a[n, i], 4]]]
```

In this example

```
a[1,1][1]=1;a[1,1][2]=2;a[1,1][3]=3;a[1,1][4]=4;
a[1,1][2]=5;
```

Then I can get the `A[1,1]={1,5,3,4};`And I can handle the matrix with any corner mark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [ReplacePart[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)

```
A[1, 1] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
ReplacePart[A[1, 1], 2 -> 5]
{1, 5, 3, 4}
```